# Loading related entities in BaseScript (DbContext)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, eager-loading

I have a BaseScript, in the Script there is a GetAll which not load related entities.

In the DbContext there is LazyLodingEnabled disabled (false).

Following some Code to understand my issue. In this example it doesn't load the user and messageViews when I want to get the messages by language.

BaseScript

```
public abstract class BaseScript<TEntity> where TEntity : EntityBase
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        using (EntityDbContext ctx = new EntityDbContext())
        {
            return ctx.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

MessageScript

```
public class MessageScript : BaseScript<Message>
    {
        public IEnumerable<Message> GetAllByLanguagePublic(string language)
        {
            return this.GetAllPublic().Where(x => x.Language == language).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Message entity:

```
public class Message : EntityBase
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MessageView> MessageViews { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your question is "Why aren't `User` and `MessageViews` loaded?" If that is the case, you are answering yourself. If you disable lazy loading, you have to load these properties explicitly, using `Include` (for example):

Maybe in your `BaseScript.GetAll` you want to return an `IQueryable` instead of a `IEnumerable` so the query will not be exectued yet (do not call `ToList()`). Then, in your `GetAllByLanguagePublic` method you could do this:

```
public class MessageScript : BaseScript<Message>
{
    public IEnumerable<Message> GetAllByLanguagePublic(string language)
    {
        return this.GetAll()
            .Include(x => x.User)
            .Include(x => x.MessageViews)
            .Where(x => x.Language == language).ToList();
    }
}
```

Note that you need to include `System.Data.Entity` to use `Include` with lambda expression.